# I need to set the text of a <td> as a variable

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tampermonkey

At work we use a table that puts items into a list. The shipment ID number is a link...but to and old site we no longer use. I'd like to grab the shipment ID from the  and use it in a variable to replace the link with the new site's link.

There are how ever a few problems I've run into. First of all, I do not have permissions to directly edit the html code of the page, I'm using tamperMonkey to alter code on my computer only.

Second, the table doesn't have a great use of classes and ones the ones they do use are reused for other  that I don't need to grab (at least not yet).

Here is an example of the code for one of the  that I need to grab:

```
<td class="filterable check hero 169800136261000-1 ">
        <div class="relative">
            <a href="https://oldWebsite.com/services/report/shipment-display.html?shipmentId=169800136261000" target="_blank">169800136261000</a>
        </div>
    </td>
```

`<div class="relative">` is used inside just about every  in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select every `a` with a `href` that includes `shipmentId`, and replace its `href` with the new site:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('table a[href*="shipmentId"]')
  .forEach((a) => {
    const shipmentId = a.href.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    a.href = 'https://newsite.com/somepage?shipmentId=' + shipmentId;
  });
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="filterable check hero 169800136261000-1 ">
      <div class="relative">
        <a href="https://oldWebsite.com/services/report/shipment-display.html?shipmentId=169800136261000" target="_blank">169800136261000</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So that works like a charm (minus one detail) I took out [0] where the variable is being set so that it does all the shipment IDs on the page rather than just the first one.

I'm also modifying this snippet for another part on the page which includes letters as well as number and in some cases just numbers. what would I put in place of /\d+$/ in order to search for such things?

Comment: Since it's already iterating over all `a`s with `shipmentId`s via `querySelectorAll` and `forEach`, I think it *shouldn't* need any changes..? The `[0]` there is to select the regular expression matching string from the `.match` call (which returns a regular expression object, not a string). You could match word characters with `\w`

Comment: Too be honest, I don't understand your code entirely, but taking out [0] worked. I tried combinations of changing const to var with and without [0] and it seemed that just taking out [0] got it working past just the first one.

and for adding letters into my search for another <td> i used /[A-Z0-9]+$/ in place of /\d+$/, as I will only ever need capital letters.

Thank you IMMENSELY for your help!